# Solving modular equation with multiplication

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Let's imagine I have the following equation:

`(x * b) % m == a`

I know a, b and m and want to solve for x.

I know that if I could find the modular inverse of b (mod m), it's trivially solvable.
In some cases however, modular inverse is not defined, but the equation has a solution.

For instance

```
a=11973
b=24253
m=18113
x=58
```

In this case, `(x * b) % m == a` is true, but `gcd(b, m) == 307` and therefore the inverse is not defined.

Is there a better way to solve such an equation?

Comment: Looks like if all of a,b,m have the same gcd, I can divide all of them by it and make it work. But I'm not sure I understand what I'm doing, would appreciate an explanation.

Comment: See the linked dupes for how to solve the congruence $\,bx\equiv a\pmod{m}\ \ $